# SE Data: rand() fixed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer

When answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6855895/50552), I wrote up this [SQL answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/107592/), which works fine from my machine.

However, on SE data, it always picks the same winner. Is it possible that SE Data fixes `rand()` to a specific number?  If so, why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data explorer caches results; if you run identical queries, it will only call the database once, and deliver the cached result on subsequent queries.

Comment: That explains it, perhaps SE Data could explain a warning for queries using `rand()`